# How to get elements of common value present in all items of Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
var  rowsList = [
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "4fwdw-3wxs-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200},
                                {subDataRowId: "76d88372", amount: 9999}
                              ]
                    },              
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "373d2-1bfb-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "4dss", amount: 300},
                                {subDataRowId: "vxy", amount: 200},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 9999}
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "99ssd-1bfb-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "vxy", amount: 800},
                                {subDataRowId: "mdn", amount: 300},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200}
                              ]
                    }
                ];
```

How to get the filtered list based on having common *subDataRowId* in ALL subrows.
Expected output looking for is as below -

```
rowWiseSubrowFoundArray = [
                            [
                              {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                              {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200}
                            ],              
                            [
                              {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                              {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 9999}
                            ],
                             [
                               {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                               {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200}
                            ]
                    ];
```

I am trying to find common items which are present in ALL the Array items.
I tried like below by fetching duplicate items and iterating it with 'rowList' subrows.
But not getting expected output.

```
//
findDuplicateItemsInArray = (array) => {
    let arrayItem = {};
    let duplicateItems = [];
    array.forEach(function (itemIndex) {
        if (!arrayItem[itemIndex])
            arrayItem[itemIndex] = 0;
        arrayItem[itemIndex] += 1;
    })

    for (var prop in arrayItem) {
        if (arrayItem[prop] >= 2) {
            duplicateItems.push(prop);
        }
    }
    return duplicateItems;
}

// get all subrows
let subrows = [];           
rowsList.forEach((row) => {
    row.subrows.forEach((subrow)=> {
        subrows.push(subrow);
    });
});

//get unique subrows 
const uniqueSubrowsArray = findDuplicateItemsInArray(subrows.map((subrow) => subrow.subDataRowId));

console.log(uniqueSubrowsArray);

let rowWiseSubrowFoundArray = [];

rowsList.forEach((row) => { 
      let subrowFound = [];
      
    
      row.subrows.forEach((subrow) =>{
            uniqueSubrowsArray.forEach((uniqueSubrow)=>{
                    if(uniqueSubrow == subrow.subDataRowId){
            subrowFound.push(subrow);
                    }
            })                  
      });
      
    rowWiseSubrowFoundArray.push(subrowFound);      
});

console.log('rowWiseSubrowFoundArray', rowWiseSubrowFoundArray);
```

**Fiddle Link -**

https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/e64atjds/74/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```js
var  rowsList = [
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "4fwdw-3wxs-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200},
                                {subDataRowId: "76d88372", amount: 9999}
                              ]
                    },              
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "373d2-1bfb-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "4dss", amount: 300},
                                {subDataRowId: "vxy", amount: 200},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 9999}
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                        otherAttribute: "99ssd-1bfb-4b60-a46b-175a07f7f53e",
                        subrows:[
                                {subDataRowId: "abc", amount: 4000},
                                {subDataRowId: "vxy", amount: 800},
                                {subDataRowId: "mdn", amount: 300},
                                {subDataRowId: "lmn", amount: 200}
                              ]
                    }
                ];


const filterInput = (inputIds) => rowsList.map(val => 
val.subrows.filter(row => inputIds.indexOf(row.subDataRowId) !== -1));

const filteredData = filterInput(["abc", "lmn"]); //Pass the input Ids for filtering

console.log(filteredData);
```